# Excel multiple IF statements or macro's to solve this problem?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, nested, multiple-arguments

I'm trying to make multiple IF statements in Excel help my club convert event registrations into a template which can import into a scoring program.

The registration export places 3 attributes into a single cell. I need a way to separate those 3 attributes into 3 difference cells for the import template. Each attribute has 4-5 possibilities. I've been trying `IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH` which let's me identify 1 attribute being present.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Production",G12,1)),"Production","")`
```

*Desired outcome in red text:*

[image: https://imgur.com/a/trc1fmU]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Maybe this will help:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(B$2,$A3)),TRIM(LEFT((SUBSTITUTE(MID($A3,FIND(":",$A3,FIND(B$2,$A3))+2,255),",",REPT(" ",255))),255)),"")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Amazing!! I've read through this 10x and still amazed at what it's doing :) Thanks so much you've made my job for upcoming events sooooo much easier!!

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to above Ron Rosefield's layout table.

Here's another FILTERXML formula but in shorter version.

In `C6`, formula copied across and down :

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<a "&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A6,":","='"),",","' ")&"'/>","a/@"&C$5),"")
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your data, here is one way to handle it if you have Excel 2013+ with the `FILTERXML` function.

- Create an XML dividing on both the comma and the colon.
- This XML will have nodes equal to each entry in your original data.
- The value of any particular attribute will be the value of the `following-sibling`
- An `xPath` will then extract the appropriate attribute value.

---

```
C6: =IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A6,":",","),",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'"&C$5&"')]/following-sibling::*[1]"),"")
```

Fill across and down as needed.  Other attributes can be added to the header row.

[image]

Comment: Can I only add one correct answer? both this and the other answer do what I want. The other one hurts my brain less to understand though :p

Comment: @Dbaus You can only accept one answer.  But you can upvote other responses.